# Create Dynamic UI(Input form) from API Response in Mobile APP Using Outsystems

Tags: android, mobile, outsystems

I am searching for how a dynamic UI (or input form to submit user inputs) can be created in OutSystems (for my mobile application) depending upon the response of some API; that tells what kind of input elements are to be included in the form, in some order like TextView, EditText, Button, ImageView, Button and so on. This is because in my application a scenario is being raised in which there are several companies that provide forms to be filled by several employees and the employees can fill the form of the company in which they are interested (they may or may not be working in the same company) and each form is different (with different input elements respectively) and the API is hit with the logged-in access token (of the employee) and the company name whose form he has opted to fill with the form number/name that he has selected to fill (as each company may offer different variants of forms to be filled respectively). Any help would be greatly appreciated, thanks in advance.

Note: I am specifically talking about building the above scenario in an application that is developed using the OutSystems Platform.

Didn't get any proper solution on this.

Answer (score 0):

There are two approaches for the creation of the dynamic UI if you are not using Jetpack Compose.

1. Add linear layout in your layout and create a class of add respective views in linear layout.
2. Add recycler view in your layout and create a field layout in which you might and hide and show things accordingly, but in this you have to save the previous value for the item as when it scrolls.

[image]